# How to use zgrep to find out what line number or give some contextual info. surrounding a .gz file

Tags: debian, regular-expression, logs, gzip

In Debian you can use zgrep to grep through a gunzipped archive file. The reason for making a gunzip file is easy enough, files such as changelogs are vast which can be highly compressed. The issue is with zgrep you only get a specific line and no above or below info. to give contextual info. on the change itself. An example to illustrate -

```
usr/share/doc/intel-microcode$ zgrep Fallout changelog.gz
  * Implements MDS mitigation (RIDL, Fallout, Zombieload), INTEL-SA-00223
  * Implements MDS mitigation (RIDL, Fallout, Zombieload), INTEL-SA-00223
```

Now as can be seen it seems my chip was affected by RIDL, Fallout and Zombieload bugs which seem to have been fixed by a software patch INTEL-SA-00223 which is mentioned but as can be seen it's pretty incomplete.

The way out is to use zless and then / RIDL or any of the other keywords and then you know but am wanting to know if there is any other way or that's the only workaround ? FWIW did come to know that the bugs were mitigated on 2019-05-14 where Intel made software patches affecting these and various other issues on that date. I did try using 'head' and 'tail' using pipes but neither of them proved to be effective.

Comment: My understanding is that microcode can provide support for software *mitigation* of RIDL and related vulnerabilities, but a true fix requires redesigned hardware.  (Probably a fairly easy fix in the hard-wired logic of load execution units, but very hard to work around in microcode. The same [things that would fix Meltdown](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/177100/why-are-amd-processors-not-less-vulnerable-to-meltdown-and-spectre/177101#177101) would fix this. All of these cases involve letting loads read some value, but also flag as can't retire successfully. Squash to 0 would fix)

Comment: true. The thing is I had come across an zombieload article which traced back the roots to RIDL and Fallout issues. What you are saying is true in Intel's context and the reason AMD is burning rubber in front of Intel atm. And now that AMD is also using the Intel tick-tock architecture means they will be more aggressive, similar to Intel. But that I guess is story and a question for another day :)

Comment: I think Intel *did* fix Meltdown (and presumably others) at some point.  At least by Ice Lake.  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/engineering-new-protections-into-hardware.html shows a table of uarch vs. vulnerability: HW fix vs. software mitigation.  BTW, I also saw a mention of a Meltdown v3 variant that reads a system register, instead of memory, so that would be separate from load ports.

Comment: I am not saying they did, but as you have shared and many others software fixes are a compromise. Even for the latest iteration have had issues, see https://www.forbes.com/sites/daveywinder/2019/11/13/zombie-inside-intel-confirms-zombieload-2-security-threat/?ss=cybersecurity#3e97c0943f69 or rather the techchrunch article which has been doing the rounds https://techcrunch.com/2019/11/12/intel-cascade-lake-zombieload/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Zutils](https://www.nongnu.org/zutils/zutils.html) ([packaged in Debian](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/zutils)) provides a more capable version of `zgrep` which supports all the usual contextual parameters:

```sh
$ zgrep -C3 Fallout /usr/share/doc/intel-microcode/changelog.Debian.gz

  * New upstream microcode datafile 20190618
    + SECURITY UPDATE
      Implements MDS mitigation (RIDL, Fallout, Zombieload), INTEL-SA-00223
      CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127, CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091
      for Sandybridge server and Core-X processors
    + Updated Microcodes:
--

  * New upstream microcode datafile 20190514
    + SECURITY UPDATE
      Implements MDS mitigation (RIDL, Fallout, Zombieload), INTEL-SA-00223
      CVE-2018-12126, CVE-2018-12127, CVE-2018-12130, CVE-2019-11091
    + New Microcodes:
      sig 0x00030678, pf_mask 0x02, 2019-04-22, rev 0x0838, size 52224
```

You can install it with `sudo apt install zutils`.

Answer (score 5):

It is also only a workaround, but did you try

```
gzip -cd changelog.gz | grep -C <num_lines> "Fallout"
```

to display `num_lines` of context before and after the match (use `-A <num_after>` and `-B <num_before>` to fine-tune)?

Comment: that one works, is a good workaround but dunno if I should mark it as the answer. Looking to have an answer via zgrep if possible though.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `zcat` and a normal `grep`:

```
zcat changelog.gz | grep -C3 "Fallout"
```

`-C3` tells `grep` to provide 3 lines of context (3 above, 3 below).  Reduce this if you want less context.

You can tailor this further by using `-B<number>` and/or `-A<number>` instead (for 'before' and 'after' respectively.)

Comment: That one also does the trick, although it produces more than 3 lines, at least at my end it produces 4-5 lines. thank you for that bit as well.

Comment: You didn't specify how many context lines in your question, so I guessed.  Will edit my answer.